# Referencing assets in data property or in method in vue 3 with vite

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am just starting out with Vue 3 and vite and everything is working well in development. However, when I build the app for production, the assets declared in the data property are ignored and throw a 404 in the production build. Here is what the data object looks like...

```
data() {
    return {
      testimonials: [
        {
          customer_name: "John Doe.",
          comment: "Some customer comment here...",
          image: "/src/assets/img/awesome_customer.png",
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
}
```

Referencing the asset as `"/src/assets/img/awesome_customer.png"` works in the template tag and production bundles it properly but not if it is used in the data property or in a method.

With the vue-cli we'd use the `require()` but I've not managed to get it to work in vite any  ideas on how I can achieve this?

UPDATE:
I set up a sample repo [here](https://github.com/geneowak/vue3-test) demonstrating what am referring to. The readme contains the steps to reproduce.

Comment: did you try out `"assets/img/awesome_customer.png"` or `"@/assets/img/awesome_customer.png"`

Comment: yes, none of that works in production... The above code works in development but in production, the assets are not added to the build. Am guessing there should be a way of making them visible during production build, something equivalent to `require("/src/assets/img/awesome_customer.png")`

Comment: Upgrading to vite 2.0 and importing the images instead of referencing them directly in the data object solved the issue. Though am wondering if there is a better approach.

You can follow the discussion [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1241)

Comment: I think there's a better one by placing the images in public folder

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading to vite 2.0 and importing the images instead of referencing them directly in the data object solved the issue. Though am wondering if there is a better approach.

You can follow the discussion [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1241)